# Execute C language input file on linux

Tags: c, linux, bash, shell

I don't understand how different between

a.  `./target <input`
  b. `./target <$(cat input)`
  c. `./target $(<input)`

`./target` is a C program and input is a file or payload

I want to know that how are they different and are there any more techniques or method?

Comment: I'd personally just use `cat input | ./target`.

Comment: You indulge in [UUoC — Useless use of `cat`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat), then, @SamPagenkopf:

Answer (score 2):

Two of the three notations are peculiar to Bash; all three are shell notations.  The programs that are run need to process the data in quite different ways.

1. (**`./target <input`** — [input redirection](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Redirecting-Input)): the target program needs to read standard input to get the information.

   ```
   #include <stdio.h>

   int main(void)
   {
       int c;
       while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
           putchar(c);
       return 0;
   }
   ```
2. (**`./target <$(cat input)`** — [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution)): the target program needs to open the file name specified in a command-line argument to get the information.

   ```
   #include <stdio.h>

   int main(int argc, char **argv)
   {
       if (argc != 2)
       {
           fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s file\n", argv[0]);
           return 1;
       }
       FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
       if (fp == 0)
       {
           fprintf(stderr, "%s: failed to open file '%s' for reading\n",
                   argv[0], argv[1]);
           return 1;
       }

       int c;
       while ((c = getc(fp)) != EOF)
           putchar(c);

       fclose(fp);
       return 0;
   }
   ```
3. (**`./target $(<input)`** — [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution)): the target program gets the contents of the file split into words as arguments to the program, one word per argument.

   ```
   #include <stdio.h>

   int main(int argc, char **argv)
   {
       int count = 0;
       for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
       {
          count += printf(" %s", argv[i]);
          if (count > 70)
              putchar('\n'), count = 0;
       }
       return 0;
   }
   ```

The processing needed is quite different, therefore.